# How do I build a data frame row wise not column wise?

Tags: r

```
a <- "dog cat carrot cabbage"
b <- "orange cat chair cabbage"
c <- "dog phone book beach"
x <- data.frame(a,b,c)
> x
                       a                        b                    c
1 dog cat carrot cabbage orange cat chair cabbage dog phone book beach
```

So that's been built in columns. What I want is a 1 column data frame with each string as a row. How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d <- c(a,b,c)
data.frame(d)
```

Output:

```
                         d
1   dog cat carrot cabbage
2 orange cat chair cabbage
3     dog phone book beach
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `as.data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(c(a,b,c))

#        c(a, b, c)
#1   dog cat carrot cabbage
#2   orange cat chair cabbage
#3   dog phone book beach
```

---

You can also use `rbind`

```
rbind(a, b, c)

#   [,1]                      
#a "dog cat carrot cabbage"  
#b "orange cat chair cabbage"
#c "dog phone book beach"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a matrix by row and convert that to a df

```
data.frame(matrix(c(1, 7, 4, 6, 2, 0, 6, 2, 8), 3, 3, byrow = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use rbind and as.data.frame functions the desired output can be obtained.

```
as.data.frame(rbind(a,b,c))
```